# OpenLayers JavaScript sources 404

Tags: openlayers

When loading JS script to display OpenLayers in a webpage, I am getting 404 on both [stylesheet](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.4.0/css/ol.css) and [script](https://openlayers.org/en/v4.2.0/build/ol.js).

Any alternative sources for code?  Can't find it on [OpenLayers Github](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers), which is now version 5.4

Comment: There's a full range of old versions available from  https://cdnjs.com/libraries/openlayers

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/8331

this issue on github will help you out to understand.
The codes are on the cdn as Mike linked. and If you need sources not compressed, you can still get it from openlayers repository. https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/tree/v3.4.0
[image]